# jboss 7.0.0.Alpha1

Tags: jboss

hi i download jboss 7.0.0.Alpha1 but how to implement in application. because i can't run.bat file in this jboss. Please send me step by step process to run jboss 7.0.0.Alpha1.Operating system is window xp.

Comment: Need more information. JBoss won't start properly, if there is no Java in your Path, and it won't start, if the installationdirectory contains a *blank*.

Comment: You don't seem to be familiar with JBoss, so why use an alpha release of JBoss7? Start with the current stable version, it's better documented.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the *JBoss AS7 User Guide **[Quick Start](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7UserGuide)*** section?

> On Windows:
>   `cd bin`
>   `standalone.bat`
>   This will launch a single process on your system, a standalone JBoss AS server instance.